# Why dont I always see `buildscript` in gradle files?

Tags: gradle

Almost every tutorial or documentation I see explaining a gradle build file setup includes a `buildscript` section near the top of the file. However, most *real* projects I see do not have this section. Also, when a `buildscript` section is included, there seems to be two `repositories` sections and `dependencies` sections in the file.

My questions are; What exactly is the `buildscript` section and why does it appear to be optional? If it truly is optional then why does most documentation related to the subject imply it isn't? Regardless of it being optional or not, why do several sections appear to be duplicated.

[image]

Note: Most of the *real* projects I work with are based on IntelliJ's IDEs (i.e. Idea & AndroidStudio)